# discord.guild.members not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord bot but it seems like guild.members is not functioning.
Here is my code:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
    )

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

According to the tutorial (https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#how-to-make-a-discord-bot-in-the-developer-portal) the output should be

```
RealPythonTutorialBot#9643 is connected to the following guild:
RealPythonTutorialServer(id: 571759877328732195)

Guild Members:
 - aronq2
 - RealPythonTutorialBot
```

But my output is missing every member except the bot itself. I literally copy pasted the code from the tutorial but the output is still the same.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE (latest code)

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents =intents)

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
    )

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

    print(intents.members)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents =intents)
```

Comment: Where should I add this? If I paste it into my code it throws: NameError: name 'commands' is not defined

Comment: try again please

Comment: The output hasn't changed unfortunately

Comment: I think you need to share your latest code. Update the question with the latest code.